# Since the plugins are different in different mobile platforms, how phone gap can be cross-platform?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

For an look and feel of IOS or Android app we have to write the native plugins.
For example, if i developed an application in IOS and i have to port that to Android say i  have used 6 plugins(calender,air print,Email composer,photo editing,facebook,twitter ). Then probably i have to develop that plugins in android also.
. 
Apart from this, if we have to create custom plugin, it is also time consuming.

Now my question is that if we are developing simple listing application from website then phonegap is very useful since there is no need for changing any of the code.There Phonegap is cross platform .

Also when the project is heavy (more activities sorry more pages), can phonegap cause performance issues due to multiple ajax request and javascript loading?

So my question is that is phonegap reliable for an heavy and  more plugins needed app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use html and javascript for programming. So there is no chance to use ios user controls in android.

Comment: My question is that "is phonegap reliable for an heavy and more plugins needed app?"

Comment: In my personel experience, if you need performance u should use native platform coding. and programming in javascript and using web database is more complex than native coding.